# How do I populate entry fields with previously entered data currently saved in the database?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I'm creating an Android app which will allow the user to create CVs. I want the user to add all the details initially, but then have the option to return and edit if necessary. I want to repopulate the entry fields with the user's details which were entered previously (and saved to the database using SQLite).

I have a SAVE button which sends the data to the DB however I wasn't sure whether to add a LOAD button or whether the data will load automatically when the page is opened. Please advise.

I haven't pasted any code as I'm not sure if it will benefit my question right now.

ListView seems to be the most common method for displaying data however this doesn't help me as I require population of previously entered data to the original entry field.

Comment: The user can save only one CV?

Comment: @Filip123go My plan is that the user will be able to create a few different CVs using the data they insert. I like the idea of the data being edited which is why I'd prefer the database data to populate the entry fields for both viewing and editing. Any suggestions?

Comment: When the user opens the app there should be at least to buttons. Create and load.

Comment: @Filip123go I actually have those two buttons on my main Activity, new CV and existing CV... would you suggest that the existing Activity contains editable details? Am I able to click and edit on data pulled down from the database using ListView?

Comment: After tapping load, the user should be directed to a ListView with the available Cv's (preferably order by date (newest to oldest)).
After selected a Cv should not be editable. There should be a button Edit to the top left. Do not forget to notify your users to save the changes before exiting the edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be any load button in this case. The data should be fetched and populated automatically when the user navigates to the fragment or activity.

ListView can be used to display previously populated data.

Comment: I've gone ahead with ListView as opposed to trying my preferred way... I'll keep an eye open for alternatives in the meantime. Thanks!